# Is it a known IE bug? Didn't pass submit parameter to request

Tags: java, internet-explorer, webforms, atg

If we have `<form>` with at least two `<input type="text" ..>`, and a submit button `<input type="submit" name="someName" ..>` - then, when we press Enter on textfield - IE (I tried 7th version) correctly submits form, passing `submit=someName` with another params to request. But, when there is only one text field `<input type="text" ..>` (+ any number of dropdowns or checkboxes or radio) - pressing 'Enter' submits form without passing 'submit=someName' to request.

But there are some java frameworks (ATG, etc), which handle form submits by submit param, calling corresponding method in form handler. So, if there is no submit button param in request - handling of submit fails.

Have you seen such behaviour before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for it http://betweengo.com/2005/08/08/internet-explorer-form-does-not-invoke-atg-handler/

Answer (score 1):

the behavior is quite famous. to work around, if there's only one submit button in a form, create a hidden input with same name&value, so it will always be present in the request.

Comment: Be sure not to call it "submit", because I think you'll override the `.submit()` form method

Comment: actually it was my first thought - to add the same name hidden field, but it caused an another trouble on the ATG framework... and so then I had to add <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="submit"/>. It's not quite good, but it works...

Comment: @polina-morozova type="hidden"

Comment: irreputable: I said I tried already hidden field - input type="hidden" name="submit". It solves trouble written above, yes of course, but it causes a some new trouble (with ATG framework)... so i'm obliged to play with a style="display:none;". That is adding new text field solves troouble with IE, and this is quite enough